# best way to get information out of class in gazebo/c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, class, global

I am trying to get information out of a class which is launched from some gazebo c++ code. What makes this extra confusing is how the class is called (gazebo::transport::SubscriberPtr sub = node->Subscribe("~/pose/info", posesStampedCallback);). I am trying to get values out of that class as they are updated, like x_pos. In order to circumvent this mess, I tried using a global variable (x_pos), to pull the data out, but it doesn't seem to be affected. Any ideas on how to pull out variables? I assume I can't just change the "void posesStampedCallback" to "double posesStampedCallback", though I don't know why...

```
#include <gazebo/gazebo_config.h>
#include <gazebo/transport/transport.hh>
#include <gazebo/msgs/msgs.hh>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PORT 8090 
#include <pthread.h>

#include <string>

// Gazebo's API has changed between major releases. These changes are
// accounted for with #if..#endif blocks in this file.
#if GAZEBO_MAJOR_VERSION < 6
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#else
#include <gazebo/gazebo_client.hh>
#endif

double x_pos = 0;

void posesStampedCallback(ConstPosesStampedPtr &posesStamped)
{
  std::cout << posesStamped->DebugString();

  ::google::protobuf::int32 sec = posesStamped->time().sec();
  ::google::protobuf::int32 nsec = posesStamped->time().nsec();
  std::cout << "Read time: sec: " << sec << " nsec: " << nsec << std::endl;
  for (int i =0; i < posesStamped->pose_size(); ++i)
  {
    const ::gazebo::msgs::Pose &pose = posesStamped->pose(i);
    std::string name = pose.name();
//    if (name == std::string("my_velodyne")) {
      const ::gazebo::msgs::Vector3d &position = pose.position();

      double x = position.x();
      double y = position.y();
      double z = position.z();
    x_pos = 5;
      std::cout << "Read position: x: " << x
          << " y: " << y << " z: " << z << std::endl;
//    }
  }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int _argc, char **_argv)
{

        printf("started connecting to python\n");    
        int sock = 0, valread;
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
        if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        {
                printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
        }
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
        if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
        {
                printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
        }
        if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        {
                printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
        }

          // Create our node for communication
    gazebo::transport::NodePtr node(new gazebo::transport::Node());
    node->Init();

    // Listen to Gazebo pose information topic
         gazebo::transport::SubscriberPtr sub = node->Subscribe("~/pose/info", posesStampedCallback);


    while(1){
//      const ::gazebo::msgs::Pose &pose = posesStampedCallback->pose(1);
//      const ::gazebo::msgs::Vector3d &position = pose.position();
//      double x = position.x();
        std::string hello_string = std::to_string(x_pos);
        char hello[hello_string.size() + 1];
        strcpy(hello, hello_string.c_str());
//      char *hello = "request";
        char buffer[1024] = {0};
        send(sock , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 );
        printf("request sent\n");
    printf(hello);
        valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024);
        printf("\n%s\n",buffer );
        int speed = atof(buffer);
        printf("finished connecting to python\n");




    // Load gazebo as a client
#if GAZEBO_MAJOR_VERSION < 6
  gazebo::setupClient(_argc, _argv);
#else
  gazebo::client::setup(_argc, _argv);
#endif

  // Create our node for communication
  gazebo::transport::NodePtr node(new gazebo::transport::Node());
  node->Init();

  // Publish to the  velodyne topic
  gazebo::transport::PublisherPtr pub =
    node->Advertise<gazebo::msgs::Vector3d>("~/my_velodyne/vel_cmd");

  // Wait for a subscriber to connect to this publisher
  pub->WaitForConnection();

  // Create a a vector3 message
  gazebo::msgs::Vector3d msg;

  // Set the velocity in the x-component
#if GAZEBO_MAJOR_VERSION < 6
  gazebo::msgs::Set(&msg, gazebo::math::Vector3(speed, 0, 0));
#else
  gazebo::msgs::Set(&msg, ignition::math::Vector3d(speed, 0, 0));
#endif

  // Send the message
  pub->Publish(msg);

  // Make sure to shut everything down.
#if GAZEBO_MAJOR_VERSION < 6
  gazebo::shutdown();
#else
  gazebo::client::shutdown();
#endif
}
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a minimal reproducible example please https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can reduce the code, but I am not sure how reproducible it is going to be without the rest of the gazebo stack. The idea is that this script is run while the larger gazebo world is running. This code plugs in and sends in values (that part works fine). It is when I am trying to pull values out of gazebo that I run into problems.

Comment: At the very least it will make it more readable. It will also help you identify which parts of the program actually are causing the problem, and in reducing the issue to as simple a kernel as possible you might find the solution yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out (at least I am activating that callback function) (though it is giving me a segfault, but that is another issue)

anyways, the problem was that I was not initializing the client before I tried the call back. I needed
'''
      gazebo::client::setup(_argc, _argv);
'''
before the callback